# How can I use a Facebook business page elements when the manager logs in using FB connect for iOS?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium, facebook-javascript-sdk

To be more precise we are using Titanium, and want to gain access to the users's page and import the following elements:
- name of business
- cover and logo photos
- Address
- Gallery photos

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to request the manage_pages permission:

> Enables your application to retrieve access_tokens for Pages and
>   Applications that the user administrates. The access tokens can be
>   queried by calling /{user_id}/accounts via the Graph API. See here for
>   generating long-lived Page access tokens that do not expire after 60
>   days.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1

EDIT (after comment from OP):

All I can see is that if you get the manage_pages permission then access /{user_id}/accounts it returns all of the pages that user is an admin of.

Test by going here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts&version=v2.1 and clicking "submit", you should all the pages there (and that should be the same data you see when you call the API in your code).

Comment: Thanks for this. I implemented this method but now I get in return only 1 of the pages the user manages instead of all 3. Any idea why?

Comment: hmmm, no actually. I updated my answer with an easy way for you to test what data the FB API returns for a given user though...that might help.